# Python Pandas drop_duplicates - adds a new column and row to my data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I read a csv file and I want to remove duplicate entries.
When I run the commands to do that, it creates a new first row that contains column numbers and a new column that contains row numbers.
See [image]
Why does it do that and how should I fix this?

```
def remove_duplicates(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="latin-1", header = None)
    Helper.printline(f"Rows in file {file}: {df.shape[0]}")
    df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
    Helper.printline(f"Rows in file {file} with duplicates removed: {df.shape[0]}")
    df.to_csv(file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.to_csv(file, header=False, index=False)` to save the .csv file without headers and indexes.